# Prove the following $(a \cap(\neg b))\cup (a \cap c)=a\cap (\neg(b\cap(\neg c))) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove the following:
$$(a \cap(\neg b))\cup (a \cap c)=a\cap (\neg(b\cap(\neg c))) $$
What I tried to do so far is to minimize the LHS but I dont know if it enough:
$$(a \cap(\neg b))\cup (a \cap c)=a\cap (\neg b \cup c)$$
what should I write? Distributive property and its right?
now we I got is:
$$a\cap (\neg b \cup c)=a\cap (\neg(b\cap (\neg c)))$$
now just to open the RHS? this is the right way? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that for all sets $A,B,C$ we have $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) = A \cap (B \cup C)$. This is the distributive property.

So then $(A \cap (\lnot B)) \cup (A \cap C) = A \cap ((\lnot B) \cup C)$.

Then we need to show that $((\lnot B) \cup C) = (\lnot(B \cap (\lnot C))$.

We know by [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra) that $(\lnot X) \cup (\lnot Y) = \lnot(X \cap Y)$. (This is DeMorgan's Law I.)

We know by the Double Negation Law that $\lnot(\lnot X) = X$.

Let's take $(\lnot(B \cap (\lnot C))$. By DeMorgan's Law I, $\lnot(B \cap (\lnot C) = (\lnot B) \cup (\lnot(\lnot C))$. By the double negation law, $(\lnot B) \cup (\lnot(\lnot C)) = (\lnot B) \cup C$.

Therefore, $A \cap ((\lnot B) \cup C) = A \cap (\lnot(B \cap (\lnot C))$, and we are done.